# Using arrow keys to invoke methods C#

Tags: c#, winforms, events, listener, arrow-keys

I'm making a simple game in C# for a college project and at the moment the player is controlled via four directional buttons. I want to add event listeners so that I can use the arrows keys to control the game.

I've searched on-line and come across similar questions on here, however I'm not able to make any of the stuff I've found work, such as:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{          
    if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Left))
    {
        directionleft();
        e.Handled = true;
        return;
    }
}
```

If anyone is able to shed any light on how to properly use event listeners I'd be very grateful, thank you.

Comment: what is not working ? Is there any exception ?

Comment: Whilst using the code I put before, Nothing happens at all, there is no exception thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override [ProcessCmdKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.processcmdkey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{         
    if (keyData == Keys.Left)
    {
        directionleft();
        return true;
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: I've just used this to accommodate all arrow keys and this works perfectly, can you please explain what it is doing?

Comment: `ProcessCmdKey` handles keypresses before the control that has the focus gets it. This is why we return true (to tell the control that has focus that we've handled the keypress already so it shouldn't do anything). This event bubbles up to the more familiar events such as `KeyDown`. Since it's not control specific, it will be called in a WinForm object regardless of which control has focus. If you want to handle just when the Form has focus, you can use `KeyDown` but also may need to set the `KeyPreview` property of the form to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the focus on your form, otherwise it won't be able to listen to keystrokes. If you want to be able to detect keyboard input even if your form hasn't the inputfocus, use a [Keyboard hook](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook%20Keyboard%20Hook).